# Using Azure SendGrid to send emails from my work email to other work emails

Tags: azure, email, authentication, automation, sendgrid

I set up an Azure SendGrid resource in my company's Azure subscription, got my API key and wrote a C# script to send emails. It works, but the emails go to spam with an SCL=6. I expect this is because I am doing no domain authentication. (Please bear with me as I try to describe my situation, I'm still learning a lot about all this). I am sending the emails through my work/enterprise email account (XYZ@company.com) and they are going to other enterprise accounts on the same domain (company.com). My company is a large tech company with a very well known domain. I am just a user on the enterprise network as a normal vendor/employee, with this setup I don't know how I would touch DNS/SPF/DKIM options, which from what I've been reading are the main first steps to authenticate myself as the sender.

I guess my main question is: Can SendGrid be a possible solution to what I am trying to do? I want to send ~250 emails programatically, each from a template so I can substitute in recipient name and specific info, and I can do all that through C#. But is there a way I can authenticate myself so my emails do not go to spam? If not, are there alternative solutions? I'm just trying to avoid having to manually send ~250 customized template emails through Outlook.

Let me know if I need to provide more info, all answers are appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: This will always be an issue if you use an external relay instead of using your company SMTP. If you are using Office 365, you can have a look at Logic App connectors for Office365 or maybe PowerAutomate within your Office365 subscription.